# variable defined in __init__.py can not be imported

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to follow the instructions in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/ so I can perform flask/socketIO  operations in celery tasks.  My directory structure is a bit different however and I'm not having any luck with imports.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── ctasks.py
│   ├── helper.py
│   ├── saml.py
│   ├── socks.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── threads.py
│   └── views.py
├── app.py
├── config.py
├── requirements.txt
└── saml
    ├── dev
    └── prod
```

I call the app from `app.py`

```
from app import socketio, app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, port=443, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from .ctasks import subtaskcaller, make_celery
from .helper import wait_to_finish

async_mode = None

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)
cel = make_celery(app)

from .auth import SamlManager
saml_manager = SamlManager()
saml_manager.init_app(app) 
from app import views, socks, saml, helper, ctasks
```

`ctasks.py`

```
from celery import Celery
from config import *
from .helper import wait_to_finish, emitter
import time
from app import cel


def make_celery(app):
    c = Celery(app.import_name, backend=CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND, broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL)
    c.conf.update(app.config)
    taskbase = c.Task

    class ContextTask(taskbase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return taskbase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    c.Task = ContextTask
    return c

@cel.task(name='tasks.tester', serializer='pickle')
def tester():
    emitter('emit from subsubtask')
    for i in range(1, 50):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('test {0}'.format(i))
    x = True
    return x

@cel.task(name='task.subtaskcaller', serializer='pickle')
def subtaskcaller():
    emitter('emit from subtask')
    finished = tester.delay()
    wait_to_finish(finished)
    return finished
```

I am getting an error when trying to import cel from app  in `ctasks.py`:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'cel'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is \_\_init\_\_.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: I believe I am using unit correctly and have used imports similar to this in the past.  I am guessing I have something out of order, a circular import or import dependency problem.  I had a typo in my original code and have updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `__init__.py` you only have `cel`. You don't have an object called `celery` in your `__init__` file, so it can't be imported to some other file. You can try `from app import cel`.˛

EDIT:

in `__init__` you `from .ctasks import subtaskcaller, make_celery`

but in `ctasks` you import `cel` from app (which doesn't exist yet at that point, only Flask, request, and SocketIO exist at that point in time).

So you need to put your `@cel` decorated functions in yet another script, which you can import all the way at the bottom of `__init__`